# Why am I not able to install Android SDK?

Tags: java, android

I installed android sdk. When I click the android sdk manager. Then the the following error message is displayed in an alert box

> Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml,
>   reason: 
>   sun. Security. Validator. ValidatorException: 
>   PKIX path validation failed: 
>   java.security.cert.certPathValidatorException: 
>   timestamp check failed

Please help me to solve the issues.

Comment: try changing the URL from https to http

Comment: stackoverflow community going nuts i guess. They vote down all newbie questions. get a life guys.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan No, check the tooltip and you'll figure out why.

Comment: @Mayu : You are not the only one. Look at [meta question of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94382/163405). This question just happens to be on the gray area of topics. I would not give any minus more because (a) Sivakumar got his/her answer (b) he/she is probably going to make some more programming AFTER this issue is solved. So this helped on his/her programming related problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate of this site seems valid to me. You should check your system's date and time settings and maybe correct them. If this is not working, you could try to use a non-SSL connection with http:// like Kenny already mentioned in his comment.

Comment: MATTHIAS I CHANGE THE CHANGE THE SYSTEM DATE AS CORRECTLY.THEN IT WILL WORKS

Answer (score 2):

Try to use http instead of https in the settings

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link.
[Installing the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be clear, I got the trivial hint from the discussion about how to deal with newbies, and after that and reading the the error message more carefully the solution was obvious:
My (virtual) machine had an OLD TIME.
After setting the time correctly, it worked.